# Checking if a array isn't empty with FormData and Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I'm trying to see if a array sent from `FormData` javascript is not empty and if it isn't, use the array to make a directory and upload a file. It shows up as a normal array with all the indexes in `$_FILES` in the console but when for some reason it is not working on the PHP side. Here is the code that pertains to this:

model -

```
public function postStatus($status, array $image = array())
{
    if (empty($status)) {
        throw new StatusException("Status text cannot be left empty.");
    } else {
        // get the user's id based on $this->user
        $this->select->columns(array('id'))
        ->where(array('username' => $this->user));

        $query = $this->sql->getAdapter()->query(
            $this->sql->buildSqlString($this->select),
            Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE
        );

        if ($query->count() > 0) {
            foreach ($query as $result) {
                $row = $result;
            }

            $select = $this->gateway->select(array('id' => $row['id']));

            if ($select->count() > 0) {
                // update status
                $update_data = array(
                    'status' => $status,
                );

                $update = $this->gateway->update($update_data, array('id' => $row['id']));

                if ($update > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new StatusException("Error posting status.");
                }
            } else {
                // insert status
                $insert_data = array(
                    'id'     => $row['id'],
                    'status' => $row['status'],
                );

                $insert = $this->gateway->insert($insert_data);

                if ($insert > 0) {
                    // put image into status folder
                    if (count($image) > 0) { // this is the culprit I believe
                        if (!is_dir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status')) {
                            // make the status directory
                            // then insert any images if found
                            mkdir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status');

                            if (is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'])) {
                                move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status/' . $image['name']);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                throw new StatusException("Error uploading your image for your status.");
                            }
                        } else {
                            // insert any images if found
                            if (is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'])) {
                                move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status/' . $image['name']);
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                throw new StatusException("Error uploading your image for your status.");
                            }
                        }
                    } 

                    // no image
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new StatusException("Error posting status.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new StatusException("Invalid username passed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The array that is passed is as follows:

```
name: "boned.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", tmp_name: "C:\xampp\tmp\php3684.tmp", error: 0, size: 25388
```

As you can see, the array isn't empty but the code inside the model is not creating the directory and uploading the file. I've checked the error log and it isn't saying anything about creating the directory or uploading the file, so I am not sure what is going on.

Oh, I am using `FormData` for the jquery ajax call, so just in case, here is the code for it

```
$('#post-status').on('click', function() {
   if ($('#status').html() != "Status: " && $('#status').html() != "") {
       var status = $('#status').html();

       var getstatus;
       var getfile;

       var formData = new FormData();

       if (document.getElementById('status-photo') == null) {
           formData.append("statustext", status);

           getstatus = formData.get("statustext");
       } else {
           formData.append("statustext", status);
           formData.append("userfile", document.getElementById('status-photo').files[0]);

           var getstatus = formData.get("statustext");
           var getfile = formData.get("userfile");
       }


       $('#status-msg').html("");

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           url: "/members/status/post-status",
           dataType: "json",
           data: formData
       }).done(function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
           $('#status-msg').html(msg.success);
           $('#status').html('Status: ');

           $('#added-status-photos').attr('style', 'display: none;');
           $('#delete-include-pic').attr('style', 'display: none;');

           $('#include-pic').attr('style', 'display: block;');

           // update status text
           $.getJSON('/members/status/get-status', function(stat) {
                $('#current-status').html("Current Status: " + stat.status);
           });
        }).fail(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg.fail);
            $('#status-msg').html(msg.fail);

            $('#added-status-photos').attr('style', 'display: none;');
            $('#delete-include-pic').attr('style', 'display: none;');

            $('#include-pic').attr('style', 'display: block;');
        }); 
    } else {
        $('#status-msg').html("Please enter a valid status.");
        return;
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, as this is driving me nuts.

Thanks!

Update:

Sorry, I thought I put in the controller code, here it is again:

```
public function poststatusAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        try {
            $status = $this->params()->fromPost('statustext');
            $file = $this->params()->fromFiles('userfile');

            if (count($file) > 0) {
                if ($this->getStatusService()->postStatus($status, $file)) {
                    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'Status updated'));
                } 
            } else {
                if ($this->getStatusService()->postStatus($status)) {
                    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'Status updated'));
                }
            }
        } catch (StatusException $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('fail' => $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

    return $view_model;
}
```

Comment: No idea yet, but to debug, at the blocking line, try to `echo count($file);` and `var_dump($file);` to see what is going on

Comment: yeah, it's just showing a json string. not really sure what, but I'll try that again.

Comment: i know its do the `if (count($file)) { }` because I put different messages to be shown and that one was shown..

Comment: I put the whole method up for the model in case that helps

Comment: yeah I just tested it and it is showing different messages if the files are not there.. this is strange.

Comment: If that's really how your json looks php won't recognise it as a valid json object. The key name and value must be enclosed in double quotes ie `{name: "boned.jpg"}` should be `{"name": "boned.jpg"} see the php man page Example #3 on common mistakes -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I'm converting it with json_encode though so shouldn't it change it?

Comment: You're right. Do you know of a way to fix this?

Comment: It looks like this `$decoded = json_decode($image, true);` line is incorrect as $image is send as an array. Instead of `$decoded['name']` you should be able to directly access `$image['name']` no need to use json_decode

Comment: i still cannot get it to create a directory and upload the file there. :/

Comment: I've changed `if (!empty($image)) { }` to `if (count($image) > 0) { }` since it is an array but it's still not going through that condition and I am not sure why...

Comment: I went ahead and checked what was being captured before being sent via ajax and this is what I got (screenshot): https://imgur.com/a/ujnM4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be clear from my comments so I am putting the code here. You don't need to do this `$decoded = json_decode($image, true);` since $image is an `array` not a `json`.

```
if (! empty($image)) {
    if (! is_dir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status')) {
        // make the status directory
        // then insert any images if found
        mkdir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status');

        if (is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'])) {
            move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status/' . $image['name']);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new StatusException("Error uploading your image for your status.");
        }
    } else {
        // insert any images if found
        if (is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'])) {
            move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $this->user . '/status/' . $image['name']);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new StatusException("Error uploading your image for your status.");
        }
    }
}
```

Try to change the code to this and you will exactly know where the problem is happening. It looks to me you don't have privileges to create directories.

```
if (count($image) > 0) {
    $storeImagesDir = getcwd() . '/data/cache/' . $this->user . '/status';
    if (! is_dir($storeImagesDir)) {
        $dirCreated = mkdir($storeImagesDir,'0755', true);
        if(false === $dirCreated) {
            throw new StatusException("You don't have privileges to create the directory '.".$storeImagesDir."' for storing images.");
        } 
    }
    if (is_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'])) {
        $imageMoved = move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $storeImagesDir.'/'. $image['name']);
        if(false === $imageMoved) {
            throw new StatusException("The uploaded image file cannot be moved.");
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new StatusException("The uploaded image file is not found.");
    }
} else {
    throw new StatusException("Error posting status.");
}
```

Comment: Yes I changed it but it still won't create/ move the directory and file. The problem is it doesn't do the code in the if statement and I'm not sure why

Comment: sorry, forgot to update my question. Posted the updated code of my model method.

Comment: nothing in the php error log or on the page.. not sure what is happening. :(

Comment: @user2101411 Just try to do change this `if (count($image) > 0) {` to `if (!(count($image) > 0)) {` and see it that actually throws an error

Comment: @user2101411 I think this might be culprit `if ($update > 0) {
                    return true;
                }`

Comment: it's not throwing any error, the method does what its supposed to do but no status exception is being thrown. but the directory plus image are not being created and moved.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it is finally working for you :-)